# Clarfication on pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, pointer-arithmetic

```
*(*(p+a)+b)
```

If a*size is added to an address (p), then why is b*size added to *(p+a)? *(p+a) appears to be the value at that location and adding b*size to it would change its value, not the address. However, based on what I read this is meant to be added to an address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your expression, and assuming you're talking about C, p must be a pointer to a pointer. What happens is:

```
char ** p;
int a = 2;
int b = 4;

(p+a) // adds 2 * sizeof(char *)
*(p+a) // evaluates to a char *
char * c = *(p+a)
(c+b) // adds 4 * sizeof(char)
*(c+b) // evaluates to a char
```

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't think of multidimensional arrays of pointers to pointers. Then dereferencing would yield a pointer, which the compiler, or something else, allowing for value to become an address.